# Why random forest still overfitting after tuning via grid search?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, grid-search

I constructed a random forest for a continous outcome variable.

With the default settings of the randomForest function i get a train mse of 0,014 and a test mse of 0,079. I guess i have an overfitting problematic. 
So i tried tuning the parameters  nodesize mtry and netree via grid search and the lowest out of bag error. I have 14 explenatory variables.
The grid parameter you can see below:

```
hyper_grid_rf <- expand.grid(
   nodesize = seq(10, 20, 2),
   mtry = seq(2, 6, 1),
   ntree = seq(200,600,100)
 )
```

After that i get a train mse of  0,039 and test mse of 0,077. Thats for me still and overfitting problematic what  did i wrong.

Here is my whole code:

```
# # Tuning the Forest using Grid Search
# # Set Seed
 set.seed(1)
# # Defining Hyperparameters
 hyper_grid_rf <- expand.grid(
   nodesize = seq(10, 20, 2),
   mtry = seq(2, 6, 1),
   ntree = seq(200,600,100)
 )




# 
# OutOfBag Error
 oob_err <- c()
# # Write a loop over the rows of hyper_grid to train the grid of models
 for (i in 1: nrow(hyper_grid_rf)){
   # get minsplit, maxdepth values at row i
   nodesize <- hyper_grid_rf$nodesize[i]
   mtry <- hyper_grid_rf$mtry[i]
   ntree <- hyper_grid_rf$ntree[i]
   print(i)
#   # train a model and store in the list

 set.seed(1)

   model <- randomForest(LogStundenlohn ~ Geschlecht+ Bundesland + ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeit +
                           I((ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeit^2)/100)+ ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeit +
                           I((ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeit^2)/100) + DauerUnternehmenszugehörigkeit +
                           I((DauerUnternehmenszugehörigkeit^2)/100) + inverseMillsRatioPrunedCtreeInfoUs + öffenticherDienst +
                           Branche + Unternehmengroesse + Migrationshintergrund + Bildungsgrad
                         , data = subset(trainSet2015,Partizipation == 1),
                         nodesize = nodesize, mtry = mtry, ntree = ntree )
   oob_err[i] <- model$mse[max(ntree)]
 }
# 

# # Identify optimal set of hyperparmeters based on OOB error
 opt_i <- which.min(oob_err)
 print(hyper_grid_rf[opt_i,])
 bestParams_rf <- hyper_grid_rf[opt_i,]
# # Use bestParams for Forest

 set.seed(1)

 rf_grid <- randomForest( LogStundenlohn ~ Geschlecht+ Bundesland + ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeit +
                            I((ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeit^2)/100)+ ArbeitsmarkterfahrungTeilzeit +
                            I((ArbeitsmarkterfahrungVollzeit^2)/100) + DauerUnternehmenszugehörigkeit +
                            I((DauerUnternehmenszugehörigkeit^2)/100) + inverseMillsRatioPrunedCtreeInfoUs + öffenticherDienst +
                            Branche + Unternehmengroesse + Migrationshintergrund + Bildungsgrad
                          , data = subset(trainSet2015,Partizipation == 1), nodesize = bestParams_rf[,1],
                         mtry = bestParams_rf[,2], ntree = bestParams_rf[,3],
                         importance = TRUE)
# 
 pred_t_ranFor_grid <- predict(rf_grid, newdata = subset(trainSet2015,Partizipation ==1))
 pred_v_ranFor_grid <- predict(rf_grid, newdata = subset(testSet2015,Partizipation ==1))
# # MSE
 rf_mse_tr <- round(MSE(pred_t_ranFor_grid, subset(trainSet2015,Partizipation ==1)$LogStundenlohn),3)
 rf_mse_test <- round(MSE(pred_v_ranFor_grid, subset(testSet2015,Partizipation ==1)$LogStundenlohn),3)
```

Comment: Just FYI you don't need to call again `randomForest()` with the best params, you just need to use `predict()` with newdata, it will be fitted with the best params.

Comment: Note that this is hardly a coding question, so not on topic on this site. If you're sure to overfit you can try and remove columns which are not helpful, use feature engineering to create new ones..or even change the model.

Comment: Searching here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for similar question might be of help.

Comment: In principle and generally speaking, there is absolutely no reason why your training error should be comparable to your validation one; such situations are rather usual, and they do *not* necessarily constitute problematic cases. Notice also that the telltale signature of overfitting is *validation error starts increasing while training error keeps decreasing*, which is hardly the case here

Comment: but in my situation the training error increases and the test error descreases

Comment: Increasing/decreasing are not referred to *different* models, as here; the idea is applicable, say, to adding more trees in a random forest (or more iterations in a neural network): if you reach a point where adding more trees (iterations) your training error still falls while your validation error starts going up, you have just entered the overfitting area...

Comment: Long story short, "*a train mse of 0,039 and test mse of 0,077*" do not *necessarily* constitute a problem. Test error is not expected to be comparable with the training one.

Comment: okay any idea how  i can improve the performance of my rf?

Comment: You won't find an easy answer about this. We don't even know the task at hand. Try with a different model, learns what works and what not, do feature selection/feature engineering, possibly use an ensemble model, try stacking..and so on..

Comment: If your results still don't improve, possibly your data is not that informative and you need to rethink the problem.